# Matlab algorithm issue

Tags: algorithm, matlab

So guys, I have a problem developing an algorithm that takes a finite list of real numbers that are sorted in increasing order and a real number N, and

-If there exists two indices `i` and `j`, such that `1 <= i <j <= numel(L)` and `L(i)+L(j)=N`, then then algorithm returns the pair `sumToN = [L(i) L(j)]`; in the case that multiple pairs of indices exist with the required property, the function returns one of the valid pairs,

-If the equality `L(i)+L(j)=N` is not satisfied for any indices `i` and `j`, such that `1 <= i < j <= numel(L)`, the function return the empty pair `Ret`.

```
L = [1 2 2 3];
N = 3;
sumToN = 0;

for i=1:numel(L);
  for j=1:numel(L);
    if i<j;
        if L(i) + L(j) == N;

        sumToN = [L(i) L(j)];
    display(sumToN);
        else
        Ret = [0 0];
        display(Ret);
        end
    end
   end
end
```

Now, in this code that I've written in Matlab R2014, independently of the if conditions, I get a strange output: the command window displays two times the vector `sumToN` and four times the vector `Ret`. Any suggestion about how to solve this problem? I think that the algorithm is correct...

Comment: SO does not seem to support LateX markup can you edit your question so it's more readable please? thanks!

Comment: How can I do it? I need to display less or equal symbols!

Comment: old-school `<=` works :)

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is correct and the display behavior is also correct. In your loop `i<j` is satisfied 6 times. That is for the (i,j) pairs (1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4). So based on your code you should expect a display 6 times. In these pairs based on the data in L, the condition `L(i)+L(j)==3` can be satisfied twice with (1,2) and (1,3). So you get sumToN displayed twice and the rest 4 times Ret displayed.

If you want to stop as soon as you find a pair, you should return the values from this function as soon as you detect `L(i)+L(j) == N`. You should initialize Ret to [0 0] before the start of the loops and return that after the loop ends. This will return [0 0] if you do not find L(i)+L(j) == N.

Comment: And how can I stop the loop as soon as a pair is found?

Comment: If it is a function you can just return from it. If not you need to set some flag variables and break from the loops.

Answer (score 1):

Let's deconstruct your program a bit. The first thing I'm going to do is change the loop variables from `i, j` to `a, b`, because of this: [Using i and j as variables in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab/14790765#14790765).

Next I'll look at the line

```
if i<j;
```

We always want this to be the case, so let's make it that way. (Switching to `a, b` now)...

```
for a=1:numel(L)-1
   for b=a+1:numel(L)
```

Notice that the loop for `b` now begins at the value `a+1`. So `b` is *always* greater than `a` and we no longer need this check. I've also ended the `a` loop at `numel(L)-1` because there is no element after `L(numel(L))` for `b` to occupy and we want to make sure that `a+1` is always valid.
(Also note that I've removed the semicolon at the ends of the lines. They're unnecessary and effectively add a blank line to the loop.)

Now we're ready to see if the `L(a), L(b)` pair adds to `N` and if so, set our return value:

```
if L(a)+L(b) == N
   sumToN = [L(a) L(b)];
```

If you want the value displayed here, either do:

```
   display(sumToN);
```

or leave the semicolon off of the assignment `sumToN = ...`

If we're inside the `if` and we've assigned the return value, we want to stop looking for other answers. I'm going to assume at this point that you're supposed to be writing a standalone function and that this is all the function is supposed to do. To end the loops (and, indeed, any further processing of the function) you would use `return` immediately after the assignment. That makes the nested loops look like this:

```
sumToN = [0 0];
for a=1:numel(L)-1
   for b=a:numel(L)
      if L(a)+L(b) == N
         sumToN = [L(a) L(b)];
         return
      end
   end
end
```

From here, you can either add your initializations for `L` and `N` at the beginning and `disp(sumToN);` at the end for a script, or you can make a full-fledged function with a function declaration and another `end`:

```
function sumToEnd = summy(L,N)
   <all the stuff above goes here>
end
```

Things are a little more complicated if this is part of a larger script that you don't want to completely exit once you find a pair, but it's still quite possible. (You would have to use `break` twice, which exits out of a single loop each time, paired with a boolean variable to tell you when to break.)

Comment: The algorithm above doesn't seem to return the empty pair if the condition ´L(a)+L(b) == N´ isn't satisfied...

Comment: @ale42 It does for me. `sumToN = [0 0];` means that `[0 0]` will be returned if nothing overwrites it. Did you try running it?

Comment: Yep. Now it works, and the code is ligher. I've added ´display(sumToN)´ right before the return in the ´for´ loop, just before ´return´ and at the end of the program, outside the loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I've solved the problem this way:

```
L = [1 2 2 3];
N = 3;
sumToN = 0;
Ret = [0 0];

for i=1:numel(L);
  for j=1:numel(L);
    if i<j && L(i) + L(j) == N;
     sumToN = [L(i) L(j)];
    end
  end
end
if sum(sumToN) == N;
     display(sumToN);

else
     display(Ret);
end
```

But, even  if the result displayed is only one, the number of steps executed in the for loop doesn't change.