# Number of steps necessary in order to complete an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab

So guys, I've already asked a question about how to develop an algorithm [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31705861/matlab-algorithm-issue/31707080#31707080).

The reviewed code looks like this: (note that I've put the elements in the vector L all equal in order to maximize the iterations of the program)

```
L = [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2];
N = 3;
sumToN = [0 0];
Ret = [0 0];
k = 0;

for i=1:numel(L)-1;
  for j=i+1:numel(L);
      if L(i)+L(j) == N
     sumToN = [L(i) L(j)];
     display(sumToN);
     return
      end
      k=k+1
  end
end
display(sumToN);
```

The `k` variable is used to keep count of the iterations. The function that counts the number of steps of the algorithm is `(1/2)(x-1)x`, with `x` being equal to the number of elements in the vector `L`. The problem is that the exercise asks me to ensure that the algorithm completes in at most `c*numel(L)` for some positive constant `c` that does not depend on `L`. Moreover, I need to explain why this implementation completes in at most `c*length` steps.

How can I do it?

Comment: Your code does not completes in at most `c * numel(L)`, it completes in at most `numel(L) * numel(L)` which is very different.

Comment: I know, but how can I make the algorithm complete that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a contradiction in your statements: You say that your algorithm complete in `x * (x - 1) / 2` (`x = numel(L)`), and you want to prove that your algorithm completes in `c * x` (where `c` is a constant). This is not possible!

Let's assume there is `c1` such as `x * (x - 1) / 2 <= c1 * x`, it means that `x` must be less than `2 * c1 + 1`, so if I take `x = 3 * c1`, the inequation is not true anymore, so there is no `c` such as `x * (x - 1) / 2 <= c * x` for all `x`.

Here is an algorithm that works in `O(x)` with a **sorted** array (from your previous question):

```
i = 1
j = length (L)
while i < j
    if L(i) + L(j) == N
        sumToN = [L(i) L(j)];
        break
    elseif L(i) + L(j) <  N
        i = i + 1;
    elseif L(i) + L(j) >  N
        j = j - 1;
    end
end
```

Basically, you start with the first (smallest) value and the last (larger) value, and you move towards the middle of the array `L` as long as your two indexes do not cross.

Comment: Yep, I know... But there's any way - even changing the algorithm - that allows to get the same result with a linear function?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Another way i think you could only have a single `for`, to get that condition you're talking about, would be to process a bit like this :

- for each value of L, check if there is the value (L-N) in your list L (use a command to find a value in your list, that would return the position in the list)
- If the value exist, put that pair of position in your new table.

You should be able to get the same result with a single `for`.

Comment: This is just a cover for the second `for` loop because the find as a `O(n)` complexity, so the global complexity would still be `O(n ** 2)` (the second `for` is hidden inside the `find` function). Knowing that the array is sorted, the complexity of `find` drops to `O(log(n))` but the global complexity would still be `O(n * log(n)) > c * n` for `n` large enough.

Comment: Indeed, as i finished, i saw your edid with a sorted array, which makes sense to reduce notably the complexity. But i don't really see a way to match the acceptance criteria of the question though.

Comment: If you follow the link provided by the OP, you'll see that the original question uses a sorted array. A `O(n)` algorithm is possible on a non-sorted array if you have access to a hashmap with a `O(1)` hash complexity: First you create a hashmap where the key are the value of the array and the value are the key, then for each value `a` in the array, you check if the key `N - a` is in the hashmap (assumed also `O(1)` for hashmap).